# Função de conversão CamelCase

Tags: php, camel-case

Já possuo uma função onde a mesma realiza a conversão de *strings* para *slug*.

*Abaixo darei exemplos para facilitação no entendimento de minha pergunta.*

**3 exemplos antes da conversão:**

1. `link para uma página`
2. `link página`
3. `link`

**3 exemplos depois da conversão:**

1. `link-para-uma-pagina`
2. `link-pagina`
3. `link`

Até aqui tudo bem, sempre utilizei esta função sem maiores problemas. Só que agora encontrei a necessidade de utilizar o formato [CamelCase](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) partindo já do **slug** que tenho.

Sei que existe inúmeras possibilidades disso ser feito, por isso estou aqui, para obter a melhor resposta possível.

> Um detalhe é que, seria um *"quase"* CamelCase, pois independente da string, preciso que o primeiro caracter seja sempre em lowercase.

**3 exemplos depois da conversão do slug para o "quase" CamelCase:**

1. `linkParaUmaPagina`
2. `linkPagina`
3. `link`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui está mais uma opção:

```
    function toCamelCase($string) {
       //Converte todas as '-' em espaço em branco para a função ucwords funcionar.
       $string = str_replace('-', ' ', $string);

       return str_replace(' ', '', lcfirst(ucwords($string)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
<?php

function toCamelCase($str) {

  $newStr = '';

  //$str = preg_replace('/[`^~\'"]/', null, iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str));

  $pieces = explode('-', $str);

  for ($i=0; $i < count($pieces); $i++) {

    if ($i > 0) {
      $newStr .= ucfirst($pieces[$i]);
    } else {
      $newStr .= $pieces[$i];
    }

  }

  return $newStr;

}
```

Comment: Muito bom Yure, é isso mesmo, apenas lembrando que neste caso teria que 'explodir' no '-' e não no ' ', pois o formato da string já estará em formato de slug conforme falei na pergunta `link-para-uma-pagina`. E neste caso não seria necessário também remoção de acentuações e similares.

Comment: Então sendo assim, já fiz a alteração na função.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo usando expressão regular:

```
function StrToCamelCase($m){
    return $m[1].strtoupper($m[2]);
}

$prepended_char = '-';

$str = 'link-para-uma-pagina';
echo lcfirst(str_replace($prepended_char, '', (preg_replace_callback('/(^|[ \-'.$prepended_char.'])([a-z])/','StrToCamelCase',$str))));
```

Apesar de resolver, particularmente prefiro uma solução mais simples e intuitiva usando `explode()` e laço de repetição.

O motivo é que nem sempre o uso de ER é vantajoso. Pode parecer mais elegante com menos códigos, mas isso não quer dizer que seja mais performático.

Não testei performance nesse caso específico, mas acredito que `while`, `for` ou `foreach` com `explode` seja melhor. Se ambos, `ER` ou `explode` derem um mesmo tempo de execução ou uma diferença insignificante, prefiro o jeito simples onde é mais fácil entender e dar manutenção.

ERs são sempre complicadas e obscurecem o código.

Comment: É concordo com você com o simples e intuitivo, mas fiz esta pergunta justamente para isso, para ter outras opções além do simples e intuitivo, dependendo da frequência de utilização talvez não seja tão legal "viver" fazendo laço para executar a função toda a vez, sei lá.

Comment: adicionei o motivo na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de realizar essa tarefa é usar um regex onde padrão combine o traço seguido do caracter seguinte que é expressãdo como: `-(.)` para fazer a subustituição use [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) no grupo(aquele ponto entre parenteses). Uma função anônima foi usada

```
<?php
$str = 'link-para-uma-pagina';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/-(.)/', function($item){return strtoupper($item[1]);}, $str);
echo $str;
```

Saída:

```
linkParaUmaPagina
```

O primeiro argumento de [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) é expressão regular para a substituição, o segundo é uma função anônima que deixa a captura do grupo em maiuscula por isso `$item[1]` e não `$item[0]` que é a captura de toda a expressão.

```
preg_replace_callback('/-(.)/', function($item){return strtoupper($item[1]);}, $str);
```